# QRegularExpression how i can get last matched word

Tags: qt, qregularexpression

(?i)time.?([0-9:]+) - this pattern find all texts - time=00:00:00.00

How i can get last matched element(time=00:05:01.84)  in first or second text

First text:

```
Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-11-21 11:03:11
      handler_name    : IsoMedia File Produced by Google, 5-11-2011
Output #0, mp3, to 'ssdad.mp3':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    TSSE            : Lavf54.63.104
    Stream #0:0(und): Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-11-21 11:03:11
      handler_name    : IsoMedia File Produced by Google, 5-11-2011
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (aac -> libmp3lame)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
size=    3779kB time=00:03:01.84 bitrate= 128.0kbits/s
size=    3779kB time=00:04:01.84 bitrate= 128.0kbits/s
size=    3779kB time=00:05:01.84 bitrate= 128.0kbits/s
video:0kB audio:3779kB subtitle:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead 0.008011%
```

Second text:

```
Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-11-21 11:03:11
      handler_name    : IsoMedia File Produced by Google, 5-11-2011
Output #0, mp3, to 'ssdad.mp3':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    TSSE            : Lavf54.63.104
    Stream #0:0(und): Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-11-21 11:03:11
      handler_name    : IsoMedia File Produced by Google, 5-11-2011
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (aac -> libmp3lame)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
size=    3779kB time=00:05:01.84 bitrate= 128.0kbits/s
video:0kB audio:3779kB subtitle:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead 0.008011%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the last matched element with `QRegularExpression`, you can use [global match](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregularexpression.html#global-matching) to obtain a `QRegularExpressionMatchIterator` and iterate it to the last element:

```
QString getLastTime(const QString &input)
{
    auto re = QRegularExpression { R"((?i)time.?([0-9:]+))" };
    auto matchIterator = re.globalMatch(input);
    while(matchIterator.hasNext())
    {
        auto result = matchIterator.next();
        if (!matchIterator.hasNext())
        {
            return result.captured(0);
        }
    }
    return QString{};
}
```

Alternatively, you can use [`QString::lastIndexOf`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#lastIndexOf-7) with a `QRegularExpression` to get the last match:

```
QString getLastTime2(const QString &input)
{
    auto match = QRegularExpressionMatch{};
    input.lastIndexOf(QRegularExpression { R"((?i)time.?([0-9:]+))" }, -1, &match);
    return match.captured(0);
}
```